# Unable to load related entities in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework 4.1. I need to create a WCF service which needs fetches from an existing database. I am using wsHttp binding. I have used the DbContext generator with WCF support. The following are two of the classes that have been generated:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(TestSummary))]
public partial class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual TestSummary TestSummary { get; set; }
}
```

and,

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Test))]
public partial class TestSummary
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

When I fetch all the Test objects, I do not get the TestSummary related to it. The same happens with all my other entities. Code use to fetch the Test entity:

```
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
using (TestModelContainer context = new TestModelContainer())
{
    var query = (from t in context.Tests select t);

    foreach (var t in query)
    {
        Test test = (Test)t;
        tests.Add(test);
    }
}
```

However, when I generate the classes using the DbContext generator without WCF support, all the related entities are also loaded (I tested it with a console application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your query, you are not fetching related `TestSummary` entities. You need to declare explicitly that you want to fetch related TestSummaries with adding an `Include` statement to your query.

```
var query = (from t in context.Tests.Include("TestSummary") select t);
```

Also, there is no need to create `List<Test> tests`; you may just return what you have fetched from the query;

```
using (TestModelContainer context = new TestModelContainer())
{
    var query = (from t in context.Tests select t);
    return query.ToList();
}
```