# Related child entities (Entity Framework 4) are loaded but I am unable to bind to them

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, datagrid, parent-child

I have the following SQL tables mapped to two entities (with the same properties)

```
 Two Tables look like:

 MasterPartNumbers (parent) many  -> many     MasterPartsLists (children)
 (PK) pnID                                   (PK)(FK) parentPnID
      pn                                     (PK)     pnID   
      pnDesc                                          qty
                                                      price
                                                      isAssembly
```

Note: these SQL tables were simply added to my Model, mappings left as is. So they each have the primary/foreign key properties as Navigation Properties.

I have an `ObservableCollection` i'm using as the `ItemsSource` binding, and it looks like:

```
         public ObservableCollection<MasterPartNumber> SelectedAssyBOMLineItems
    {
        get
        {

            if (this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN != null)
            {
                var bomItems = (from childMpn in this._context.MasterPartNumbers
                                from childMpl in this._context.MasterPartsLists
                                where childMpl.parentPnID == this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN.pnID //this._selectedTopLevelAssyPn.pnID is simply the selected "Parent" part number in an adjacent ListBox on my View (usercontrol). It is of type MasterPartNumber
                                where childMpl.pnID == childMpn.pnID
                                select childMpn
                                );

                return this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems = new ObservableCollection<MasterPartNumber>(bomItems);
            }
            return this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems;
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedAssyBOMLineItems");
        }
```

So good so far-- I am able to bind to all of the properties of MasterPartNumbers, and I'm looking at the intended subset of data provided by my query in my DataGrid. HOWEVER, I am unable to bind to any of the MasterPartNumbers.MasterPartsLists properties. I can see that they are loaded when I step through the debugger. What am I missing?

I expected to just reference the binding path as {Binding MasterPartsList.isAssy} by loading the related entities from the context with something like a `_context.MasterPartNumbers.Include("MasterPartsLists")` in my query.

The behavior I am looking for is similar to the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461526/unable-to-load-related-entities-in-a-wcf-service?rq=1)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What method are you trying to display the MasterPartsLists? Is it a TreeView or a Master/Detail pattern? Also makes more sense to show the EF class than the database schema.

Comment: it's just a master/detail pattern --just trying bind to the properties of both tables. My EF classes look exactly the same (one-many relationship from MasterPartNumbers to MasterPartsList via MasterPartNumbers.pnID == MasterPartsLists.parentPnID)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you most likely want the second control to bind to the first control using something like

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding MasterPartNumbers}" x:Name="MasterControl" />
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding ElementName=MasterControl, Path=SelectedItem.Children} />
```

Assuming that your MasterPartNumbers class has the form

```
class MasterPartNumbers 
{
    IEnumerable<MasterPartsLists> Children { get; }
{
```

Simple enough

```
            var bomItems = this._context.MasterPartNumbers.Include(x => x.Children);
```

You may need to import System.Entity from the EntityFramework 5.x assembly. Else you will need to use a string rather than a lambda.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. I think everything should be bind-able to the current itemsSource hooked up to the DataGrid. I essentially want to navigate down the table (using something like a context.MasterPartNumbers.Include("MasterPartsLists")) so that in my binding I can just "pull up" the relevant MasterPartsLists properties like: {Binding MasterPartsLists.isAssy} where my itemsSource is the ObservableCollection of MasterPartNumbers with the "Include" logic

Comment: That made no sense at all to me. Master Detail pattern describes two controls that are linked together, the detail control is slaved to the selected item in the master control. I think it best if you describe not the IMPLEMENTATION but the BEHAVIOR you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope that is more clear for you. the master/details portion is taken care of. I believe my issue is that the related entity data from the MasterPartsList entity is not loaded when the MasterPartNumber entity data is loaded.